# How to migrate Outlook from previous installation

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, migration

Having a hard disk with a previous installation of same version of Windows (7) and Outlook (2007), how do I migrate all its data to the current installation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not everything is stored in the .PSTs

If you want to restore your Outlook profile completely be sure to close OL and copy the following paths from the backup to the new installation:

> - *%appdata%\Microsoft\Outlook*
> - *C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Application Data\Microsoft\Signatures*
> - *C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook*

This should restore your Outlook profile including autocomplete and settings.

Comment: +1 a lot of people are completely hosed without that email address autocomplete file.

Comment: Is there a Documents and Settings in Windows 7?

Comment: The corresponding path in Windows 7 is "C:\Users\USERNAME\Application Data". Therein you will find \Roaming which equals %appdata% and \Local which equals \Local Settings

Comment: Instead of C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME you can use %USERPROFILE% instead.

Comment: Instead of C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Application Data you can use %APPDATA% instead.

Answer (score 1):

These two guides can help you out:
[Backup your Outlook Inbox](http://www.vista4beginners.com/Backup-your-Outlook-Inbox)

[How to migrate to Outlook 2007 & Windows Vista](http://vista4beginners.com/migrate-to-Outlook-2007-and-Windows-Vista)

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the PST file of old one to paste new one ( correct folder )

to find the pst file  : http://ask-leo.com/where_is_my_outlook_pst_file_located.html

Edit 2 : 
Here you can find the various folder for all different setting of outlook

http://www.slipstick.com/config/backup2007.asp

Comment: With that I copied all mails, but I didn't got the accounts configuration, do you know how do I get that?

Comment: http://www.howto-outlook.com/faq/newprofile.htm

Answer (score 0):

Outlook saves all data in *.pst files. What you have to do is to find and open that file in the new installation of Outlook.

The file is probably named "Outlook.pst", and resides under "C:\Users\< Your-old-profile-name >\AppData\Local\Microsoft\".

In your current installation of Outlook there's an option to open *.pst files, under the "File / Open / Outlook Data File" menu item. Choose the file you want to open (the one from the previous installation), and you will see that the file appears under your ordinary folders in Outlook, with a header similar to "Private Folders". You will find all your old items there.

I don't have Outlook on my computer, so the menu item names may not be exact, but I hope my post will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If the other drive is bootable you could use the Windows Easy Transfer program found in Accessories, it should be able to move your mail and settings to your new installation.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you want to save the "remembered" email address, remember to make a copy of your outlook.nk2 file from C:\Documents and Settings\YOUR USERNAME\AppData\Microsoft\Outlook Folder.

Rafael